# SSIS 2012 extracting bool from .csv failing to insert to db "returned status 2"

Tags: csv, visual-studio-2012, types, ssis

Hi all quick question for you.

I have an SSIS2012 package that is reading a flat file (.csv) and is loading it into a SQL Server database table. However, I am getting an error for one of the columns when loading the OLEDB Destination:

[Flat File Source [32]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Active_Flag" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

I am wondering if this is because in the flat file (which is comma delimited), the values are literally spelled out "TRUE" or "FALSE". The advanced page on the flat file properties has it set to "DT_BOOL" which I thought was right. It was on DT_STRING originally, and that wasn't working either.

In the SQL server table the column is set up as a bit, and allows nulls. Is this because it is literally typed out TRUE/FALSE? What's the easiest way to fix this?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Easiest way to fix it is with a derived column that outputs 1 for "true" and 0 for "false".

Comment: Sorry Tab question is solved. It actually turned out there was a blank space in front of "True"/"False" in the file. Was just bad data and I missed it. Fixing that solved my issue. Thank you though, I did try that and when that didn't work that's when I knew it was something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually turned out there was a blank space in front of "True"/"False" in the file. Was just bad data and I missed it. Fixing that solved my issue. Thank you though, I did try that and when that didn't work that's when I knew it was something else.